# ls command: What does the @ in file mode mean, and how to get rid of it?

Tags: macos, terminal

After I download files on OSX and then want to use them, they often have an @ appended on the file mode whenever I do a `ls -l`. Here is an example output, see the `@` near the beginning of the line:

```
ls -l *.php
-rw-r--r--@ 1 username  staff  11179 Dec 17  2010 class.mysql.php
-rw-r--r--@ 1 username  staff     24 Nov  1  2010 info.php
-rw-r--r--@ 1 username  staff     61 Dec 23  2010 page.php
-rw-r--r--@ 1 username  staff   1157 Dec 17  2010 photo.php
```

I think it is some kind of locking meganism, is that right? And how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From the `ls` [manual](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) (`man ls`) section *The Long Format*

> `If the file or directory has extended attributes, the permissions field printed by the -l option is followed by a '@' character.`

You can then display the extended attributes with `-@`

> `-@      Display extended attribute keys and sizes in long (-l) output.`

To manipulate extended attributes you can use the `xattr` command. See for example [*How do I remove the extended attributes in Mac OS X*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833052/how-do-i-remove-the-extended-attributes-on-a-file-in-mac-osx) or *[Dealing With Extended Attributes on OS X](https://gotofritz.net/blog/geekery/os-x-extended-attibutes/)*

Comment: Thank you, very complete answer! I was just about to ask how to remove any attributes, but I see you have just updated your post :)

Comment: I just realized later that there was a second part in the question :-)