# I can't write to a file that I own on /Users/shared

Tags: permission, macos, sharing

I am running macos Sierra 10.12.1

It's a plain text file. I've put rw permission on it for all users, but the only way that I can write to it is by having an account with admin privileges use sudo to edit it. It claims to be 'locked' in TextEdit, and I don't have the permission to unlock it.

Here is it ls -l@ entry:

```
-rw-rw-rw-@ 1 thelma  staff  15424 Oct 28 12:47 addresses
    com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot     50 
    com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineOldestSnapshot     50
```

Comment: What are the permission of the directory itself?

Comment: the directory listing:drwxrwxrwt  20 root  wheel  680 Oct 28 19:55 /Users/shared

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ls command: What does the @ in file mode mean, and how to get rid of it?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97241/ls-command-what-does-the-in-file-mode-mean-and-how-to-get-rid-of-it)

Comment: @Wildcard I would argue this is a different scenario. The other question simply addresses what the `@` indicates. This question is about the specific extended attributes that the OP has already shown are present on the file.

Answer (score 1):

A "Locked" file is a different situation than file permissions and who owns it and can write to it. It's actually locked for everyone including the owner.

*This will require admin privileges*

1. Go to finder
2. locate the file.
3. select it and right click then choose "get info" or cmd+i (with it selected)
4. Uncheck the "locked" option.

If this isn't the actual issue then permissions are wrong and need changed.

EDIT: Apologies for the delay in editing! Been rather busy!

tldr; Perhaps you are not a member of the group associate with the file.

I tested this with a file myself. I navigated into /Users/Shared (Capital S for shared, this is wrong in your question heading, just to ensure correct directory), and then made a file with:

```
touch test-file-permissions
```

This created a file named test-file-permissions with group assess of wheel, and administrator group. This was the outcome:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 MyCurrentUserName wheel  0 Nov  3 19:00 test-permissions
```

From here I was able to both use Nano, a terminal editor to edit the file and sublime text without `sudo`(GUI and terminal editors can make a difference for example: when editing the /etc/sudoers file it must be done by a terminal editor and command `visudo`).

I then changed the file permissions for group ownership and permissions with editing writes still in my abilities and no problems.

*Note*: We have two commands here. `chmod` and `chown`.

```
chown -- change file owner and group
```

AND

```
chmod -- change file modes or Access Control Lists
```

Using chmod I tested personal rights to the file without group permissions, and then even changed which groups had ownership with no problems with requiring `sudo` to change the file. I didn't need it, simply put.

*Note:* TheGroupNameIChangedTo is a group on my machine. I, the user account, must be a member of this group, in which case I am.

Don't know your groups? Run command: `groups`

Moving on..

```
chown MyUserName:TheGroupNameIChangedTo test-permissions
chmod -v 0660 test-permissions
```

Outcome:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 MyUserName TheGroupNameIChangedTo  27 Nov  3 19:11 test-permissions
```

Therefore I believe your group may not be correct on the file. Your two user accounts, Admin and Standard must be a member of the same group. A solution would be to create one named whatever you like that doesn't conflict with existing, and add both users to it **DO NOT ADD STANDARD USER TO WHEEL GROUP FOR SECURITY PURPOSES, ALTHOUGH THIS WILL SOLVE IT IN A WAY, IT POSSES A RISK** .. I emphasize this because I understand and actually applaud with your two account system here separating Admin and Standard users. This is very smart!

Update me if this is what you want/needed, I'll keep peeking in on the question. My answer may be a bit out of the way, but I wanted to cover everything for you and others viewing the question. I'm open to edits from viewers. All else aside, it'll still get edited later for clarity.

Comment: The OP already stated they don't have permission to unlock the file.

Comment: I provided the answer if it is locked in the terms being presented here. No question was actually stated, only implied. Therefore OP needs administrator privileges to solve their problem, as stated in my answer.

Comment: @Jahhein: in Info, the locked option is already off.  The permissions on the file are rw for all; the permissions on the directory are as shown in comment above.  I have full access to admin privileges if necessary.

Comment: @tubedogg: I didn't say that I can't unlock the file: I keep a separate account for things that need admin status. I don't want to have to bring it up every time I want to change a textfile.

Comment: Updated Thelma. You will need a group that both your administrator user and standard user are a member of, I'm updating this post again for the 3rd time, I just noticed this second comment.

Comment: @Jahhein: I'm not clear as to whether you noticed the post where I found a fix for the problem.  It's a fix from the terminal command line which is fine w/ me.  I don't care whether I need to fix it as admin or me, so I don't need extra groups, although I'd be surprised if admin isn't already in the group 'staff'' with which the file is associated.  But are you saying that with your fix the file would be unlockable from 'Info' on the graphic screen?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it. Apparently, the file carried extra extended attributes and ACL stuff that needed to be removed. I used the instructions in the link below to remove them and now I can again write to my own file.

These instructions clear an entire folder, but I could use them for a file, too

```
 http://garote.livejournal.com/249703.html
```